# I try to download a image to firebase but I getting an error "Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'String"

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I try to follow a video on Youtube try to download image and show it but I getting error in one line I don't know to do.

```
var pet: Pet! {
        didSet{

            ImgPhotoPet.image = UIImage(named: "Drako")
            viewContenido.frame.size.height = 140.0
            ImgPhotoPet.frame.size.width = (viewContenido.frame.size.width * 0.32) / 100
            //ImgBackgroundPet.frame.size.width = (viewContenido.frame.size.width * 0.68) / 100
            CardInfo.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
            ImgPhotoPet.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0
            ImgPhotoPet.layer.masksToBounds = true
            LblNamePet.text = pet.namePet
            LblAgePet.text = pet.birthDay
```

---

In this line I have this error "Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'String'"

```
if  let imageDownloadURL = pet.URLImagePet {
```

---

```
            let imageStorageRef = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: imageDownloadURL)

            imageStorageRef.getData(maxSize: 2 * 1024 * 1024, completion: { [weak self] (data, error) in
                if let error = error {
                    print("Error \(error)")
                } else {
                   if let imageData = data{
                        DispatchQueue.main.sync {
                            let image = UIImage(data: imageData)
                            self?.ImgPhotoPet.image = image
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In the future, please include complete code - the pet var/Class shown in the question doesn't have a property or function called `URLImagePet` so we also don't know what that is. It may be handy to future readers to have the question updated so they can see the use case for that property.

Comment: Ok Jay thanks and sorry, I'm noob here and in xcode too, next time I try to include all code :), but the Warren's answer it's right, I deleted ```if``` and that is all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable `pet.URLImagePet` is non-optional so `if let` is redundant. You need only `let`

This will fix the syntax error.

```
let imageDownloadURL = pet.URLImagePet
let imageStorageRef = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: imageDownloadURL)
etc...
```

*Unrelated style point*: Try to use lower camel cased names for variables. `urlImagePet` vs `URLImagePet`. Upper cases make the names look like class names as opposed to instances of the class.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer and your recommendation, I will start using it.